# Question about the combinations of an alphabet with a fixed number of positions

Tags: combinatorics

Let $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^n, \{B_i\}_{i=1}^m$ be two finite collections. If I select $k$ elements from $\{A_i\}$ from the first collection without replacement, and $k$ elements in $\{B_i\}$ with replacement, how many combinations of k elements from each set do I have?

My best guess is ${n \choose k} * m^k$.

An example selection would be $A_2, A_4, ... , A_{2k}$ and $B_1, B_2, ... , B_k$ if $2k \leq n$, where the collection is not ordered.

Unfortunately I am unable to find some decent lectures online about counting. If anyone has recommendations on this topic, please link them in the comments.

Comment: Your best guess is correct (except that what you’re counting is not, as you described it, combinations of $k$ elements).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott The problem is vaguely stated. His "best guess" is correct if he wants an unordered sample from the first collection and an ordered sample from the second. Maybe that's what was intended. On the other hand, maybe he's missing a $k!$ factor.

Comment: @bof: That’s the most reasonable interpretation of the description, I think, but it is indeed possible that he meant to select the first batch sequentially rather than as a lump, in which case the correct count would of course be $k!\binom{n}km^k$.